# How do I pass credentials to a machine so I can use Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey() on it?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, credentials, remote-access

[This .NET API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws%28VS.71%29.aspx) works OK if I'm trying to open the Registry in a machine that's in the same domain as I am (and my logged-on user has admin rights on the target machine).

It gets tricky if it's an out-of-domain machine with a different, local administrative user (of whom I do have the password).

I tried to use [WNetUseConnection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385482%28VS.85%29.aspx) (which has served me well in the past in situations where what I wanted was to read a remote disk file) prior to calling OpenRemoteBaseKey(), but no dice -- I get an access denied exception.

Clearly, I must pass credentials some other way, but how?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What I've used successfully to access files on a computer is the following code:

```
    #region imports 
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
        private static extern bool LogonUser(string 
        lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, 
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref 
IntPtr phToken); 


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
        SetLastError = true)] 
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle 
        ); 

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
        SetLastError = true)] 
        public extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr 
        existingTokenHandle, 
        int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr 
        duplicateTokenHandle); 
        #endregion 
        #region logon consts 
        // logon types 
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2; 
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3; 
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9; 

        // logon providers 
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0; 
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3; 
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2; 
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1; 
        #endregion
```

And then for signing in part, just use:

```
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero; 

        bool isSuccess = LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", 
        LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token); 
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext person = new WindowsIdentity(token).Impersonate()) 
        { 
        //do your thing 
         person.Undo(); 
        }
```

As you might see, "Undo()" will make that you are no longer signed in as that user. So don't use it before you're done. But don't forget to use it!

Comment: Could I keep the "token" variable around a long time, and then use the "using/Undo()" block at various points in tame using the same token?"

Comment: I Think so. It's the Impersonate that actually signs in. What I've used is a "GetImpersonation()" that returns a WindowsImpersonationContext like above

Comment: But won't person.Undo() render the person variable unusable for a future access? My plan was to call LogonUser(), keep the "token" pointer, and then use various using blocks exactly like yours, each with creation of a new WindowsImpersonationContext object.

Comment: Or maybe I may NOT call Undo() each time, just using(person) { something(); }, then using(person) { something_else(); }, and then when I'm sure I won't need the connection further, person.Undo()?

Comment: Then you will dispose your object each time and not being able to undo it (I think). Perhaps instead just leave a person hanging and don't have "using" but instead call dispose explicitly

Comment: You have DuplicateToken in your imports but it is never used in your example, what is that for?

Comment: @Scott It might be for me not cleaning up the code very well :)

Comment: I have tried with your code i am still not able to access the registry of a remote meachine using openremotebasekey

Comment: @hari I think that might be another problem

Comment: If you check the [.NET source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/ae6ee4d226c3f126.html), you'll see Dispose calls Undo. So Undo is already called automatically at the end of the using block.