# How to Impersonate a user for a file copy over the network when dns or netbios is not available

Tags: c#, impersonation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Password Protected Network Drives in Windows in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563724/accessing-password-protected-network-drives-in-windows-in-c)

I have ComputerA on DomainA running as userA needing to copy a very large file to ComputerB on WorkgroupB which has the ip of 192.168.10.2 to a windows share that only userB has write access to.

There is no netbios or dns resolving so the computer must be refrenced by IP

I first I tried

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity UserB = new WindowsIdentity("192.168.10.2\\UserB", "PasswordB"); //Execption
WindowsImpersonationContext contex = UserB.Impersonate()
File.Copy(@"d:\bigfile", @"\\192.168.10.2\bifgile");
contex.Undo();
```

but I get a `System.Security.SecurityException` "The name provided is not a properly formed account name."

So I tried

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity webinfinty = new WindowsIdentity("ComputerB\\UserB", "PasswordB"); //Execption
```

But I get "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." error instead.

so then I tried

```
IntPtr token;
bool succeded = LogonUser("UserB", "192.168.10.2", "PasswordB", LogonTypes.Network, LogonProviders.Default, out token);
if (!succeded)
{
     throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
WindowsImpersonationContext contex = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token);
(...)
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LogonUser(
      string principal,
      string authority,
      string password,
      LogonTypes logonType,
      LogonProviders logonProvider,
      out IntPtr token);
```

but `LogonUser` returns false with the win32 error "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"

I know my username and password are fine, I have logged on to computerB as that user.

Any reccomandations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563724/accessing-password-protected-network-drives-in-windows-in-c/2563809#2563809) apply to what you're attempting?

---

(Copy of linked answer)

> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541504/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-a-machine-so-i-can-use-microsoft-win32-registrykey-o) got me to where I needed to be pretty quickly in
>   the same case.
>
> Here's how I adapted the code:
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>
> /// <summary>
> /// Implements P/Invoke Interop calls to the operating system.
> /// </summary>
> internal static class NativeMethods
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// The type of logon operation to perform.
>     /// </summary>
>     internal enum LogonType : int
>     {
>         /// <summary>
>         /// This logon type is intended for users who will be interactively
>         /// using the computer, such as a user being logged on by a
>         /// terminal server, remote shell, or similar process.
>         /// This logon type has the additional expense of caching logon
>         /// information for disconnected operations; therefore, it is
>         /// inappropriate for some client/server applications, such as a
>         /// mail server.
>         /// </summary>
>         Interactive = 2,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// This logon type is intended for high performance servers to
>         /// authenticate plaintext passwords.
>         /// The LogonUser function does not cache credentials for this
>         /// logon type.
>         /// </summary>
>         Network = 3,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// This logon type is intended for batch servers, where processes
>         /// may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct
>         /// intervention.  This type is also for higher performance servers
>         /// that process many plaintext authentication attempts at a time,
>         /// such as mail or Web servers.
>         /// The LogonUser function does not cache credentials for this
>         /// logon type.
>         /// </summary>
>         Batch = 4,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Indicates a service-type logon.  The account provided must have
>         /// the service privilege enabled.
>         /// </summary>
>         Service = 5,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// This logon type is for GINA DLLs that log on users who will be
>         /// interactively using the computer.
>         /// This logon type can generate a unique audit record that shows
>         /// when the workstation was unlocked.
>         /// </summary>
>         Unlock = 7,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// This logon type preserves the name and password in the
>         /// authentication package, which allows the server to make
>         /// connections to other network servers while impersonating the
>         /// client.  A server can accept plaintext credentials from a
>         /// client, call LogonUser, verify that the user can access the
>         /// system across the network, and still communicate with other
>         /// servers.
>         /// NOTE: Windows NT:  This value is not supported.
>         /// </summary>
>         NetworkCleartext = 8,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// This logon type allows the caller to clone its current token
>         /// and specify new credentials for outbound connections.  The new
>         /// logon session has the same local identifier but uses different
>         /// credentials for other network connections.
>         /// NOTE: This logon type is supported only by the
>         /// LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 logon provider.
>         /// NOTE: Windows NT:  This value is not supported.
>         /// </summary>
>         NewCredentials = 9
>     }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Specifies the logon provider.
>     /// </summary>
>     internal enum LogonProvider : int
>     {
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Use the standard logon provider for the system.
>         /// The default security provider is negotiate, unless you pass
>         /// NULL for the domain name and the user name is not in UPN format.
>         /// In this case, the default provider is NTLM.
>         /// NOTE: Windows 2000/NT:   The default security provider is NTLM.
>         /// </summary>
>         Default = 0,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Use this provider if you'll be authenticating against a Windows
>         /// NT 3.51 domain controller (uses the NT 3.51 logon provider).
>         /// </summary>
>         WinNT35 = 1,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Use the NTLM logon provider.
>         /// </summary>
>         WinNT40 = 2,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Use the negotiate logon provider.
>         /// </summary>
>         WinNT50 = 3
>     }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// The type of logon operation to perform.
>     /// </summary>
>     internal enum SecurityImpersonationLevel : int
>     {
>         /// <summary>
>         /// The server process cannot obtain identification information
>         /// about the client, and it cannot impersonate the client.  It is
>         /// defined with no value given, and thus, by ANSI C rules,
>         /// defaults to a value of zero.
>         /// </summary>
>         Anonymous = 0,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// The server process can obtain information about the client,
>         /// such as security identifiers and privileges, but it cannot
>         /// impersonate the client.  This is useful for servers that export
>         /// their own objects, for example, database products that export
>         /// tables and views.  Using the retrieved client-security
>         /// information, the server can make access-validation decisions
>         /// without being able to use other services that are using the
>         /// client's security context.
>         /// </summary>
>         Identification = 1,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// The server process can impersonate the client's security
>         /// context on its local system.  The server cannot impersonate the
>         /// client on remote systems.
>         /// </summary>
>         Impersonation = 2,
>
>         /// <summary>
>         /// The server process can impersonate the client's security
>         /// context on remote systems.
>         /// NOTE: Windows NT:  This impersonation level is not supported.
>         /// </summary>
>         Delegation = 3
>     }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Logs on the user.
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
>     /// <param name="domain">The domain.</param>
>     /// <param name="password">The password.</param>
>     /// <param name="logonType">Type of the logon.</param>
>     /// <param name="logonProvider">The logon provider.</param>
>     /// <param name="token">The token.</param>
>     /// <returns>True if the function succeeds, false if the function fails.
>     /// To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</returns>
>     [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
>     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
>     internal static extern bool LogonUser(
>         string userName,
>         string domain,
>         string password,
>         LogonType logonType,
>         LogonProvider logonProvider,
>         out IntPtr token);
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Duplicates the token.
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="existingTokenHandle">The existing token
>     /// handle.</param>
>     /// <param name="securityImpersonationLevel">The security impersonation
>     /// level.</param>
>     /// <param name="duplicateTokenHandle">The duplicate token
>     /// handle.</param>
>     /// <returns>True if the function succeeds, false if the function fails.
>     /// To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</returns>
>     [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
>     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
>     internal static extern bool DuplicateToken(
>         IntPtr existingTokenHandle,
>         SecurityImpersonationLevel securityImpersonationLevel,
>         out IntPtr duplicateTokenHandle);
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Closes the handle.
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="handle">The handle.</param>
>     /// <returns>True if the function succeeds, false if the function fails.
>     /// To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</returns>
>     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
>     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
>     internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
> }
> ```
>
> followed by
>
> ```
>     IntPtr token;
>
>     if (!NativeMethods.LogonUser(
>         this.userName,
>         this.domain,
>         this.password,
>         NativeMethods.LogonType.NewCredentials,
>         NativeMethods.LogonProvider.Default,
>         out token))
>     {
>         throw new Win32Exception();
>     }
>
>     try
>     {
>         IntPtr tokenDuplicate;
>
>         if (!NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(
>             token,
>             NativeMethods.SecurityImpersonationLevel.Impersonation,
>             out tokenDuplicate))
>         {
>             throw new Win32Exception();
>         }
>
>         try
>         {
>             using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext =
>                 new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate).Impersonate())
>             {
>                 // Do stuff with your share here.
>
>                 impersonationContext.Undo();
>                 return;
>             }
>         }
>         finally
>         {
>             if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
>             {
>                 if (!NativeMethods.CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate))
>                 {
>                     // Uncomment if you need to know this case.
>                     ////throw new Win32Exception();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
>         {
>             if (!NativeMethods.CloseHandle(token))
>             {
>                 // Uncomment if you need to know this case.
>                 ////throw new Win32Exception();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: It would appear that my 3rd way (very close to what you did) is the correct way. Using your code it worked fine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You are my Hero! I worked on this Problem for such a long time and with so may different approaches. None worked with IP. GREAT! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
private const int LOGON32_LOGON_TYPE = 9;
private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 3;
```

This parameters should work in

```
if ( LogonUser(userName,   
                               domain,
                               password,
                               **LOGON32_LOGON_TYPE,
                               LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,**
                               ref token ) != 0 )      
                {
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head, did you try

```
user@computer
```

instead of

```
computer\user
```

?

Comment: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.