# Windows Impersonation and duplicating tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I have an asp.net project where the request will delegate work to the background (via quartz.net). The web application is using windows authentication and impersonation.

I would also like to impersonate the current user on the background thread as well. I have read how to impersonate a user with a supplied domain name, username and password and calling out the kernel. That method works.

```
IntPtr token;
var successfullLogon = LogonUser(userName, password, domain, logonType, logonProvider, out token);
if(successfullLogon == false)
{
    var errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(errorCode);
}
```

That works, but it requires me to either provide a specific username/password, or have the user enter their password. neither situation is ideal.

What I would like is to pass the token from the user's identity from the request to the background and then impersonate the user from this existing token. I read that I should be able to call DuplicateHandle,

```
var token = ((WindowsIdentity)Request.User.Identity).GetToken().ToInt64();
var token = new IntPrt(token from request);
IntPtr duplicate;
try
{
    if(NaviteMethod.DuplicateToken(token, SecurityImpersonationLevel.Impersonate, out duplicate) == false)
    {
        var errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(errorCode);
    }

    using(var identity = new WindowsIdentity(duplicate))
    using(var context = identity.Impersonate())
    {
        //do work
        context.Undo();
    }
}
finally
{
    if(duplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        NaviteMethod.CloseHandler(duplicate);
    }
}
```

But I get an exception *Overlapped I/O operation is in progress*

The NativeMethod calls come from this post: [How do I pass credentials to a machine so I can use Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey() on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541504/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-a-machine-so-i-can-use-microsoft-win32-registrykey)

Is it possible to use the current user's token and impersonate that user on a background thread? If so how can this be done and are there any user access rights required for this to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot bypass the "LogonUser". One option is to use [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). The second one you already have it if you replace the first two lines of your second code block with the first block code.

Comment: I'm already using impersonation for the http requests. this code executes in the background so it's independent of the asp.net impersonation. the second option is what I currently have in place and looks to be the solution I will stick with.

Comment: Excellent choice. It will save your time.