# site level folder read/write/delete permissions from web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I am hoping that someone could offer some assistance in helping implement some functionality on a production server.

I have a link on a VB.net aspx page that needs to open a folder in a subdirectory of a web site and provide read and write permissions so that files can be copied into and read from as well as deleted. ONLY from this folder.

I have this functionality working on a dev and demo PC but they are both on my domain. Clicking the link opens Windows Explorer and I can copy /cut &  Paste, etc.

The public/production PC is on the LAN, but not part of the domain. I know there are ways to allow folder read/write permissions on a public server like this but I am not too sure on the safest way to do this. The upside, the only users that need to have read/write/delete access are employees. Forms Authentication, ASP Membership directs non-employees to other pages within the site. Likewise, the membership directs employees to an admin section of the site.

This is Server 03, Web Edition, so no AD, using IIS 6, and SSEE.

Any sample code, links to articles, MSDN etc would all be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest solution is to provide read/write access to directory from IIS. another approach is to tap into the kernel's logon methods and impersonate a user who has read/write access. here.

[How do I pass credentials to a machine so I can use Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey() on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541504/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-a-machine-so-i-can-use-microsoft-win32-registrykey) this post my provide some insight into how to go about impersonating a user to perform an operation.

Comment: Your link looks promising I will look it over.