# How do I use SecureZeroMemory with LogonUser when impersonating a user?

Tags: c#, security, pinvoke, impersonation, securezeromemory

When is it necessary or recommended to add the function [SecureZeroMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Neither [this MSFT sample for WindowsImpersonationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx), or these Stackoverflow questions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/125356/328397) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2541504/328397) even mention the SecureZeroMemory function.

Should I implement this function (or perhaps ask the owner of the accepted answers to include this feature?)

Comment: You do not need to use that. It just a measure taken so that you do not have user passwords in memory after use. For same efect in c# you can use char array and Array.Clear function or SecureString class.

Answer (score 1):

`SecureZeroMemory` is, as the name would imply, a way to set a block of memory to all `0x00` values, although it has the following idiosyncracies:

- It will never be optimized out by a compiler
- ...
- Actually, that's the only difference I can think of.

As @user629926 mentions, the `SecureString` class, as awkward as it can be to use, is a "safe" way of holding onto `string` data in memory without worrying that if your app crashes, someone can sift through the memory dump and find your raw sensitive data in it.

Comment: You didn't mention why is it a good or bad idea to use this function you merely described its function which wasn't the question